# Como colocar anúncio dentro do AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

Queria colocar um banner de anuncio dentro do `AlertDialog` , tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa criar um [AlertDialog personalizado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655641/2570426)<sup>(en)</sup>. Logo depois você insere o `AdView` referenciando o `dialog` ao `findViewByID`. Veja abaixo:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Veja mais detalhe em relação ao `AdMob`, dê uma lida aqui na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).